# Sending form with VueJS + Laravel results in 419 error

Tags: forms, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, form-submit

I am using the awesome **Laravel 5.7** for one of my projects.
Although I am using **VueJS** within *Laravel Blade* views to be able to powerfully manipulate the visual interface, it is **not** an SPA, i.e., the navigation between pages is the traditional one, using *Laravel routes*.

In this scenario, I want to send a form to Laravel, to a typical `store` Laravel controller method using the route in *action* prop of the `form` tag. Nothing special.

The weird behaviour comes when submitting the form, because Laravel always returns a 419 error, saying:

> Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again

And the session has obviously not expired...

I know it has to be with the `xx_session` cookie:

- I have noticed that all of my requests have a `xx_session` cookie (correct).
- The problem is the 419 response always sends a `Set-Cookie` header, which changes the value of that cookie. And each time I resend the form, the `xx_session` is updated to the last one received, but another `Set-Cookie` header changes its value again, and they never match...

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you including the `_token` and `_method` fields in the form body?

Comment: I am using the `@csrf` Blade directive, and no `_method` as verb is `POST`, not `PUT`... Anyway, adding it did not do the trick :(